# Turning off eslint rule for a specific line

Tags: javascript, jshint, eslint

In order to turn off linting rule for a particular line in JSHint we use the following rule:

```
/* jshint ignore:start*/
$scope.someVar = ConstructorFunction();
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

I have been trying to locate the equivalent of the above for eslint.

Comment: Use `eslint-disable-next-line`:

Comment: Starting with ESLint v7, you can [specify the reason](https://github.com/eslint/rfcs/pull/33/files) for disabling a given rule in the same comment.

Comment: To disable multiple specific rules: `// eslint-disable-line no-console, max-len`

Answer (score 3065, accepted):

To disable next line:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
var thing = new Thing();
```

Or use the single line syntax:

```
var thing = new Thing(); // eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define
```

See the [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules#using-configuration-comments-1)

---

Thanks to [KhalilRavanna comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line#comment57636051_29592334)

> if you don't care about specificity you can just do //eslint-disable-line and it appears to disable all rules for the given line

```
var thing = new Thing() // eslint-disable-line
```

Comment: Now I get another eslint problem:  warning  Unexpected comment inline with code       no-inline-comments   :(

Comment: Works great for me. Also if you don't care about specificity you can just do `//eslint-disable-line` and it appears to disable all rules for the given line.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me; I'm running eslint 3.8.0. I have to use /*eslint-disable */ and /*eslint-enable */. Any idea why this might be? I like the single line approach

Comment: @SomethingOn had the same problem, turned out I had `--no-inline-config` turned on, which `Prevent comments from changing config or rules`

Comment: Not working with "gulp-eslint": "^3.0.1". I have to use /*eslint-disable */

Comment: `eslint-disable-next-line` is probably best as a lot of linters will auto format to move the inline comment to next. eg. in a case you need to disable for a variable that is a function name (in our case its unchangable legacy)

Comment: Btw, you could not add comments after this until very recently (v7 2020) which added a new feature to allow you to add `-- my comment here` after you disable the rule: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/commit/cf46df70158a4ed4c09d5c9d655c07dc6df3ff5e

Comment: It seems that I had `tslint:disable-next-line`, and it didn't work. The `eslint-disable-next-line` command works better.

Comment: Yuck.  This is pollution.  eslint is supposed to make things *pretty* if you're doing valid things.

Comment: In typescript, if setting the name of the rule, I have to add `@typescript-eslint/` before the rule name: `// eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`

Answer (score 684):

### Update

ESlint has now been updated with a better way disable a single line

```
// eslint-disable-next-line $rulename
```

see @goofballLogic's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29592334/437).

NOTE Though, the above not working for jsx eg React webapp

---

### Old answer

You can use the following [pair of disable/ enable comments](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules#using-configuration-comments-1) - please note only `/*eslint ... */` syntax  working, `//eslint ...` NOT working

```
/* eslint-disable */
alert('suppress all warnings between comments')
/* eslint-enable */

/* eslint-disable eqeqeq */
alert('suppress specific warning eg eqeqeq between comments')
/* eslint-enable eqeqeq */
```

---

To disable a *specific warning* e.g. `eqeqeq` for an entire file, you can [include a comment at the top of the file](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules#using-configuration-comments):

```
/* eslint eqeqeq:0 */
```

And when multi-rule to ignore, list them ON 1 LINE separated with a space

```
/* eslint jsx-a11y/alt-text:0 react/jsx-no-duplicate-props:0 */
```

Comment: BTW, it seems that the `//` comment syntax does not work…

Comment: Also a side note, i was looking for disabling eslint for one line in html. this works :thumbsup:

Comment: This is best answer to me

Comment: In typescript, if setting the name of the rule, I have to add `@typescript-eslint/` before the rule name: `// eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`

Answer (score 274):

You can also disable a **specific rule/rules** (rather than all) by specifying them in the enable (open) and disable (close) blocks:

```
/* eslint-disable no-alert, no-console */

alert('foo');
console.log('bar');

/* eslint-enable no-alert */
```

via @goofballMagic's link above: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuring-rules

Comment: Be sure your eslint comments pass eslint! -> `Expected exception block, space or tab after '/*' in comment.` :)

Comment: I use a combination of `prettier` and `eslint` to format my code. This does not allow for inline comments. Many `/* eslint-disable-next-line ... */` statements are hard to read and to spot in the code.

Answer (score 132):

From [Configuring ESLint - Disabling Rules with Inline Comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments):

```js
/* eslint-disable no-alert, no-console */


/* eslint-disable */

alert('foo');

/* eslint-enable */


/* eslint-disable no-alert, no-console */

alert('foo');
console.log('bar');

/* eslint-enable no-alert, no-console */


/* eslint-disable */

alert('foo');


/* eslint-disable no-alert */

alert('foo');


alert('foo'); // eslint-disable-line

// eslint-disable-next-line
alert('foo');


alert('foo'); // eslint-disable-line no-alert

// eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
alert('foo');


alert('foo'); // eslint-disable-line no-alert, quotes, semi

// eslint-disable-next-line no-alert, quotes, semi
alert('foo');


foo(); // eslint-disable-line example/rule-name
```

Answer (score 86):

### Answer

You can use an inline comment: `// eslint-disable-next-line rule-name`.

### Example

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log('eslint will ignore the no-console on this line of code');
```

### Reference

ESLint - [Disabling Rules with Inline Comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules)

Comment: Just fwiw, it appears the most recent docs page (as of today, at least) with examples of how to temporarily turn things off with comments has moved from the one you provide to https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules

Answer (score 34):

The general end of line comment, `// eslint-disable-line`, does not need anything after it: no need to look up a code to specify what you wish ES Lint to ignore.

If you need to have any syntax ignored for any reason other than a quick debugging, you have problems: why not update your delint config?

I enjoy `// eslint-disable-line` to allow me to insert `console` for a quick inspection of a service, without my development environment holding me back because of the breach of protocol. (I generally ban `console`, and use a logging class - which sometimes builds upon `console`.)

Comment: No offence, but this is the same solution as the accepted answer, so not sure how this helps?

Comment: Do NOT do this. If you have 5 errors on the line, they will all be ignored. Always explicitly set the rule which is to be ignored or the kids will make a mess.

Comment: @FilipDupanović If your programmers can make a mess within a single line of code, just because eslint is not looking over their shoulders for a single line. There is really something else going wrong at your company... That said, saying what rule you wish to ignore makes it more clear why you put the disable line there in the first place.

Comment: @EdwinStoteler Well, then the software would have 2 problems: the programmers AND the sloppiness in the eslint rules. It's no excuse moving the fault to just on one and harder to fix cause of the problem.

Comment: @FilipDupanović Maybe eslint should have a meta rule for requiring explicit rule to ignore?  Maybe it already does.

Comment: @Josef.B there's a non-standard rule for that:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/master/docs/rules/no-abusive-eslint-disable.md

It works really nicely.

Comment: 'Do not do this' you say — but if your client insists against all reason on running eslint non-stop during the dev process whilst watching files, being told 'won't compile as you have a  two spaces instead of one, and a console.log' is reallyl annoying. Ofc use of pre-push hooks (even pre-commit if you must) would help there, but you can't tell some clients, even when they pay you to tell them.

Answer (score 24):

Or for multiple ignores on the next line, string the rules using commas

```
// eslint-disable-next-line class-methods-use-this, no-unused-vars
```

Answer (score 17):

My answer, similar to others given, but shows how you can also add a comment to yourself on the same line.

```
// eslint-disable-line // THIS WON"T WORK
```

Use `--` if you also need to write a comment on that line (eg. maybe why eslint is disabled)

```
// eslint-disable-line -- comment to self (This DOES work)
```

Can be used in conjunction with specific eslint rules to ignore:

```
// eslint-disable-line no-console -- comment to self (This Also Works!)
```

Comment: Excellent. This is what I was looking for, nice and clean with a custom comment. Mine is: /* eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved -- file is created at runtime */

Answer (score 14):

To disable a single rule for the rest of the file below:

```
/* eslint no-undef: "off"*/
const uploadData = new FormData();
```

Comment: or `/* eslint-disable no-new */`

Answer (score 14):

To disable all rules on a specific line:

```
alert('foo'); // eslint-disable-line
```

Answer (score 5):

To disable all rules on a specific line:

```
// @ts-ignore
$scope.someVar = ConstructorFunction();
```

Comment: As of this date in 2023, this works in VSCode, and in typescriptlang.org Playground, when all other ESLint rules provided here do not work. There is probably something specific to the ESLint rules themselves, that preclude the other directives from working, perhaps a difference between TS and ES? Anyone?

Comment: @TonyG In VS 2022 with TS/React, I had to add a qualifier before the rule name: `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface`. The warning tooltip told me the name.

Answer (score 3):

I have disabled that perticular line some thing below

```
<TableRow
   key={index}
   className={classes.tableRow}
   onClick={this.onSelectedValue.bind(this, user)} // eslint-disable-line
>{index}
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

single line comment did not work for me inside a react dumb functional component, I have used file level disabling by adding 
/* eslint-disable insertEslintErrorDefinitionHere */

(normally if you are using vs code and getting eslint error, you can click on the line which gives error and a bulb would show up in vs code, right click on the light bulb and choose any disable option and vs code will do it for you.)

Answer (score -8):

You can add the files which give error to .eslintignore file in your project.Like for all the .vue files just add /*.vue

Comment: it asked for one line, not the whole file

Comment: He could also stop using eslint... If your just going to ignore every file that has issue why use it at all?