# How do I make the Visual Studio Code linter ignore a line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example this, at the top of a node.js source file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

...or unused local variables, etc.

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line - many of the responses there should work.  The docs seem to cover most of what's listed there as well though.  https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-only-for-a-group-of-files

Answer (score 44):

Late to the party but in VSCode you can write `// @ts-ignore` just before the line you want to ignore.

[image]
[image]

It is important to notice that it will just ignore the line after the declaration.

[image]

There is more info about it [in the official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript).

Comment: This works in Visual Studio 2019 as well. use `// @ts-ignore` for an individual line of code, or `// @ts-nocheck` to exclude the entire file.

Answer (score 5):

For unused local variable, you can configure the user or the workspace settings.

From the preference menu item, choose user/workspace settings:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
    // Unused local variable.
    "javascript.validate.lint.unusedVariables": "ignore"
}
```

As for `#!/usr/bin/env node` what is the undesirable behavior that you want disable?

Comment: Thanks - I know about the global options, just want to disable it on a line by line basis. The linter is complaining about the shebang which is valid for node scripts (but not valid js of course).

Answer (score 3):

You can tell jshint to ignore lines, or just certain rules. Here's how to ignore a line, from http://jshint.com/docs/

```
// Code here will be linted with JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:start */
// Code here will be ignored by JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

Now, I'm just assuming that Code honors these directive.

Comment: Thanks, tried it (as well as jslint options), doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Finally at a real computer, and I tried, too. Indeed, those directives are ignored by the builtin javascript linter. I tried ignore syntax from several linters, and they all failed.    
`/*jshint ignore:start */ /*jsl:ignore */ /*ignore jslint start*/ /*eslint-disable */ /*jslint vars: false  */ // jshint ignore:line`
This leads me to believe that VSCode is doing its own thing. So, it probably needs to go to UserVoice here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 3):

You can select suggestion from PROBLEMS by hovering over the red x in the circle and then click on the lamp :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just in case, this is for ESLint extension, which is not currently built-in. Related: https://eslint.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via inline - e.g.: `// eslint-disable-next-line [RULE]` on the line prior to the line of code you want it to ignore. The `RULE` is optional, and will tell it to ignore a specific rule; if you don't specify one, it will tell it to ignore all rules.

Lots of other options available  - see the docs for more detail:  https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments.