# Disable JS validation on a line by line basis in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm building a website using Cherrpy, and I have in my code lines such as `if (vacant < parseInt({{warnLevel}}),10) {`. `{{warnLevel}}` is replaced by a variable I pass from a Python script, allowing me to set variables externally. However, this results in a lot of errors, as, although this works, VSCode doesn't recognise this as valid JS. Is there a way I can disable JS validation for a specific line? I've tried `// @ts-ignore` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980166/how-do-i-make-the-visual-studio-code-linter-ignore-a-line) but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add either

```
// eslint-disable-line
```

at the end of a line

or

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

on the line before

more details [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments)

note there is no reason to install an extra extension. The eslint extension already offers these options

[image]

note you can [configure any rules you want by adding comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules)

Answer (score 0):

install
[eslint-disable-snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=drKnoxy.eslint-disable-snippets) extention for this purpose.

you can include snippets for ignoring; a block, the current line, or the next line.

[image: extention preview]

Comment: This looks good, what specifically would I use to disable this error? Can I just set it to ignore all?

Comment: you should put youre code between /* eslint-disable \*/ 
/* eslint-enable */ to ignore all errors

Comment: The errors are still showing up. This is JS embedded in HTML, if that matters

Comment: this extention seems to work in js files try it in an external javascript file and tell me  the results

Comment: Still getting the warnings. Edit: I figured it out lol, I had to install ESLint and disable the built in validation

Comment: nice. happy to hear