# Disable wavy yellow underline in vs code for HTML

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

[image]

How do I ignore this error. I have used the `id` attribute for some tags in order to reference them by id in javascript, but it shows this error:

> CSS id selector '...' not found.

Please tell me how to ignore or disable this error.

Comment: This is surely coming from an extension. Check Any CSS extension installed in VSCode

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980166/how-do-i-make-the-visual-studio-code-linter-ignore-a-line

Answer (score 0):

maybe your css is not formatted properly.

try:

```
<style>
#phone {
your css here;
}
</style>
```

You need to make sure you mark the code with # to show that it's an id and not a class or something else.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: First section of answer no longer valid as of the lastest updates since original post which removed the `css.validation` option. [see](https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css/commit/e198dc381cd2142a89aef262e7b59d34390395a4)**

---

If you are using the HTML CSS Support extension by ecmel, you can go to `.vscode/settings.json` and add

```
"css.validation": {
    "id": false,
    "class": false
}
```

This will turn off css validation for class name and id.

More information on this at the Visual Studio MarketPlace for this extension under Selector Validation [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css) or the Github repository readme [Selector Validation Section](https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css#selector-validation)

---

Note: 
1) Also don't forget to add a comma after the setting that comes before (as JSON format is comma separated).

Example:

```
{
    "java.codeGeneration.generateComments": true,
    "css.styleSheets": [
        // (1)
        "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "src/main/resources/static/css/styles.css"
    ],
    "css.validation": {
        "id": false,
        "class": true
    }
}
```

2. Sometimes you need to restart / close and reopen vscode after saving changed to the file for them take effect.
3. There is a way to configure styleSheets. This next bit is taken from their documentation see [Additional Styles Section](https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css#additional-style-sheets):

> Additional Style Sheets
>
> If it is not possible to specify local or remote styles in HTML or via
> template inheritance, they can be specified in VS Code settings per
> workspace folder in .vscode/settings.json and will suggest for all
> HTML files within that workspace folder:
>
> .vscode/settings.json
>
> ```
> "css.styleSheets": [
>
>     // (1)
>     "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
>
>     // (2)
>     "/site.css",
>
>     // (3)
>     "site.css",
>
>     // (4)
>     "./site.css" 
> ]
> ```