# ESLint Disallow Use of Alert (no-alert)

Tags: javascript, html, alert, onerror, eslint

how can i turn the following alert into an acceptable alert for ESLint?

```
svg.onerror = function() {
    alert("File cannot be loaded");
};
```

My build fails because apparently i cant use "alert". I want to call this alert when there is an issue loading something. This code works successfully but it does not comply with ESLint.

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-alert

how can i modify my code to make it build successfully?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off eslint rule for a specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line)

Answer (score 16):

If you think you have a good reason for not observing an eslint setting, then you can disable that specific rule for that specific line by specifying `eslint-disable-line` in a comment on the offending line, like so:

```
svg.onerror = function() {
    alert("File cannot be loaded");  // eslint-disable-line no-alert
};
```

A better solution might be to implement a modal or show an error to the user in another less-intrusive way (eg: toggle visibility of an error element, or use something like Bootstrap's modal).

Comment: is there a way i can make the alert comply with eslint standard? they give an example in the link i gave above, but i dont understand it.

Comment: Yep! The relevant section of those documents is: "This rule is aimed at catching debugging code that should be removed and popup UI elements that **should be replaced with less obtrusive, custom UIs**."

In this case, you could place something like a `<div id="svg-error" class="warning" style="display: none;">Couldn't load SVG!</div>` near the element you're working with. Then, in the svg's `onerror` event, you'd do something like `$('#svg-error').show()` to show the error instead of doing an alert. Make sense?

Comment: but it's impossible to actual have a pop up dialog? is this correct? because i want to have a box pop up stating the error.

Comment: I'm not sure what's available in your specific case, but you could use or implement something similar to [Bootstrap's modal component](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp). This would give you the UI feedback you're looking for, as well as satisfy ESLint.

Comment: yeah i considered bootstrap but i cant use it. i can use jquery if that helps.

Comment: If jQuery UI is an option, then you might want to look at [jQuery UI's Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). If not, you'll need to implement similar functionality.

Answer (score 7):

Some ESLint rules don't make sense to include in every project, and `no-alert` is definitely one of them. While critics might say `alert` is obtrusive, that fails to account for the fact that *obtrusive can be good!*

To disable this rule, disable it in your ESLint configuration file by setting it to "off."

```
...
"rules": {
    ...
    "no-alert": "off",
    ...
}
```

[ESlint: Turning off a specific rule across a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002574/eslint-turning-off-a-specific-rule-across-a-project)