# ESLint no-undef - js issue with BigCommerce

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce, eslint

I've got this code in a .js file that I'm running through ESLint. But it's throwing an error about this line: `iFrameResize({`.

Saying: `error  'iFrameResize' is not defined  no-undef`.

If I define it like this: `const iFrameResize()`

My code no longer works, how do I make ESLint happy and keep the code working?

```
export default class Page extends PageManager {

before(next) {
    next();
}

loaded(next) {
    next();
}

after(next) {
    const url = Url.parse(location.href, true);
    const IC_PAGE = '/international-checkout';
    const currentPageUrl = url.pathname;
    if (currentPageUrl.indexOf(IC_PAGE) !== -1 && $('#icForm').length === 1) {
        $(document).ready(() => {
            if ($('#icForm').length === 1) {
                if ($('.GiftStatus') && $('.GiftStatus').val() === '1') {
                    alert('Gift Certificate is not available for international orders. Please remove Gift Certificate from shopping cart before proceeding with International Checkout.');
                    window.parent.location.href = '/cart.php';
                    return false;
                }
                $('.icformfields').each((i, e) => {
                    const currentId = $(e).attr('id');
                    const res = currentId.split('-');
                    const finalId = Number(res[1]) + 1;
                    const finalName = $(e).attr('name') + finalId;
                    $(e.currentTarget).attr('name', finalName);
                });
                document.getElementById('icIframe').src = 'https://www.internationalcheckout.com/cart.php';
                document.getElementById('icForm').submit();
                $('#icIframe').load(() => {
                    $('#icForm').remove();
                    $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $('#icIframe').offset().top,
                    }, 1000);
                    $('#icIframe').fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
        iFrameResize({
            checkOrigin: false,
            enablePublicMethods: true,
        });
    }
    next();
}

}
```

I want to know how to satisfy ESLint without disabling error reporting for the particular line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off eslint rule for a specific line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line)

Comment: @Michael I see why you think it'd be a duplicate, but I really want to know how to make ESLint happy without disabling error reporting.

Comment: I see the difference now--I missed the very last part of your question regarding "without disabling error reporting", so I agree it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are sure that the code is working on `iFrameResize()` and maybe it's the because of the architecture you've setup with js files you might just want to ignore that error. simplest is

```
// eslint-disable-line
```

which disables esilnt for that line.

Since this function definition comes from the library that is probably attaching it to the global scope which is `window` so calling it from that scope does the trick

```
window.iFrameResizer()
```

Now eslint understands that you're calling function that resides at window object, so it doesn't complain

Comment: Thanks, that definitely answers the immediate question. I wish I knew if there was a way to satisfy ESLint with out disabling the error...

Comment: It's a library called `iframe-resizer`

Comment: it's a definition that lives in the global scope. just do window.iFrameResizer()

Comment: Perfect! That does the trick, and now I'm understanding things better! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6):

It's also worth noting that eslint provides multiple ways around this.
Please see the [eslint docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals).

I would recommend adding the following to the top of your file. Use this method to define global dependencies that are only used in a couple of places:

```
/* global iFrameResize */
```

You can also provide an array:

```
/* global iFrameResize, iFrameManage, etc */
```

If you're using iFrameResize a lot or if you're dependent on something like jQuery, consider defining it as a global in your `.eslintrc` file.

```
"globals": {
    "iFrameManage": true,
}
```