# vue-language-server : Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives

Tags: vue.js

Vue.js 2.5 / Visual Studio Code editor

I am getting this es-lint warning, how can I get rid of it ?

```html
<template :slot="slotName" slot-scope="props" v-for="slotName in  $scopedSlots?Object.keys($scopedSlots):null">
    <slot :name="slotName" :row-data="props.rowData" :row-index="props.rowIndex" :row-field="props.rowField"></slot>
</template>
```

I tried to add an index, but it does not solve this issue

```html
<template :slot="slotName" slot-scope="props" v-for="(slotName, index) in  $scopedSlots?Object.keys($scopedSlots):null" :key="index">
    <slot :name="slotName" :row-data="props.rowData" :row-index="props.rowIndex" :row-field="props.rowField"></slot>
</template>
```

Comment: Possibly put the `key` on the `slot` element rather than the `template` element?

Comment: @Roy , thanks for your feedback... I tried it, es-lint warning disappear , but git a compilation error :      - `key` does not work on <slot> because slots are abstract outlets and can possibly expand into multiple elements. Use the key on a wrapping element instead.

Comment: can you reply as an answer ... I'll vote for it... I can add the :key bonding on a <div> wrapper !

Answer (score 167):

This structure causes the said error:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    {{index}}. {{item.name}}
</div>
```

You can fix it by changing the syntax like this:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
    {{index}}. {{item.name}}
</div>
```

If your items do not have any unique id field you can just write `:key="item"`.
However, for performance reasons your data should have an id field.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: Using `:key="item"` solved my problem of outputting array of string.

Answer (score 22):

You can safely ignore that warning. It comes from the eslint plugin for vue and it was a bug, [got fixed a month ago](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/commit/73a9dd46a91016504f33e5877544ebf71392841a) but maybe vetur is still using the old version of the plugin.

The key attribute has to be added to the content you pass to your component

Comment: thanks for feedback... I can ignore it, but I also can add the :key binding inside a wrapping element in the slot

Comment: Yes, you can :), it's easier if you know how to extract a `key` from the data. But if your component is rendering arbitrary data, you have no choice but to leave the user of your component provide that information (eg: a virtual scroller)

Comment: thanks .. if no key in the data, I can add index and use it... it's running fine too

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the index as the key, that's the default behaviour when no `key` is provided

Comment: Funny, I upgraded my eslint-plugin-vue to 5.0.0-beta.1 (the fix version) and it reports it as an error instead of just a warning.

Comment: Yep, I had to straight up add the `:key` directive. It may be due to me running node v10 though.

Comment: The warning still there in 2021. I used the id as key. Another option is to disable eslint for that specific line: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line

(Remember to yarn serve to see the changes if you are using hot reload)

Answer (score 15):

Let's look at a simple example here!

I'm building a To do List App. So I build a component called `Todo` and inside my `TodoList` component I will call `Todo` component like this

```
    <todo v-for="todo in todos" v-bind:key="todo" v-bind:todo="todo"></todo>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 10):

Hope this works.

Parent Component

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <VideoListItem v-for="video in videos" v-bind:key="video.title" v-bind:video="video"></VideoListItem>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import VideoListItem from "./VideoListItem";

export default {
  name: "VideoList",
  components: { VideoListItem },
  props: ["videos"]
};
</script>
```

Child Component

```
<template>
  <li>{{ video.snippet.title}}</li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "VideoListItem",
  props: ["video"]
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

======================================================

Listen => when ever you provide v-for property we need to provide v-key property.
IT ENHANCES THE PERFOMANCE OF RERENDER OUR LIST OF ITEM.

Comment: Please add a description of what this code does to improve the quality of the answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
<li class="list-group-item" v-for="server in Servers" v-bind:key="server">
```

Specify the unique key in the tag like this.

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct answer. OP needs to define the v-bind parameter in order to be recognized  (if you have an array of objects)

Answer (score 7):

Suppose you are iterating over an array named **users**, then you can do something like this:

```
<div v-for="(user,id) in users" :key="id" >
      <div class="card" >
       ...........................
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

this work for me

```
<div :class="sliderClass()" v-for="(slide,index) in slides" :key="index">
<div :class="sliderClass()" v-for="slide in slides" :key="slide.SliderID">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [the discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1294#issuecomment-686159747) in `eslint-plugin-vue`, which has the following workaround suggested:

```json
"vetur.validation.template": false,
```

Which corresponds to this UI option:

[image]

Guess no eslint validation in html is better than incorrect validation.