# Getting Error "Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives vue/require-v-for-key" in index.vue

Tags: vue.js, contentful

I am new to vue.js. I have a simple index.vue which tries to connect to contentful and display the entries from contentful. My code in index.vue looks like this:

---

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- render data of the person -->
    <h1>{{ person.fields.name }}</h1>
    <!-- render blog posts -->
    <ul>
      <li v-for="post in posts">
        {{ post.fields.title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {createClient} from '~/plugins/contentful.js'

  const client = createClient()
```

---

However when I try localhost:3000 from my browser...it comes back with the following error:

---

ERROR in ./pages/index.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\admin\pdress\pages\index.vue
  7:7  error  Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/require-v-for-key

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

---

I appreciate if someone can help me out to proceed further with my learning on vue.js please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `<li v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="index">` or `<li v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">`

Comment: You can read more about why `key` is required in [the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vue-language-server : Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608379/vue-language-server-elements-in-iteration-expect-to-have-v-bindkey-directiv)

Answer (score 16):

What @ljubadr suggested is right. You need to do this:

```
<li v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id">

<!-- OR USE SHORTCUT NOTATION -->
<li v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
```

The reason has to do with performance. Attribute `key` helps Vue determine unique items in a list. Consider the example of sorting. If your UI has a sort button for posts, then your the order of items in `post` array will change. But does that mean Vue is going to re-render entire list? Of course not! Using `:key` it can determine if the item was already rendered on UI. It simply shuffles the DOM nodes and saves expensive rendering cycles.

Secondly, if you have complex components within your list when you are using `v-for` and `:key` is not provided, then whenever the list is changed or re-ordered, it simply changes the DOM but doesn't destroy existing components and that can cause local state mismatch. That is why it is must to have `:key` attribute.

[Read Vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) for further information.

Note: Also remember that using `v-for` `index` for `:key` is a bad idea as it is not unique across your collection.

Answer (score 2):

You must define a **:key** atribute for

[`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for) directive. And for [`<transition-group>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#transition-group) tag.

for this case `v-for` you must explicit set,

```
  <li v-for="(post, i) in posts" :key="i + 10">
    {{ post.fields.title }}
  </li>
```

If you noticed you can define max two argument in the `v-for` you must define the item (post) and can define the index of the post.

Answer (score 2):

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- render data of the person -->
    <h1>{{ person.fields.name }}</h1>
    <!-- render blog posts -->
    <ul>
      <li v-for="post in posts" :key = "post">
        {{ post.fields.title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>


If this is not going to work use any unique field from your object for example if you have id in your object then,
:key = "post.id"
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information, references, context etc