# Vuejs & Vuetify : Is there a way to loop around template with datatable from vuetify (with v-slot dynamic)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have several datatable with server-side pagination, search fields and filterable fields

However, I would like to be able to generate a component and use the props to avoid modifying the same thing three times

Is there a way to loop around template with datatable from vuetify (with v-slot dynamic) ?

for example :

```
        
<template v-slot:header.id="{ header }">
    <div class="pointer border-right pa-2">
        <span class="title" @click.prevent="sortBy('id')">
            ID
            <v-icon class="ml-2">{{icon.id}}</v-icon>
        </span>
        <v-text-field v-model="searcher.ticket_id.value" type="text"
                label="Rechercher..."></v-text-field>
    </div>
</template>


<template v-slot:header.name="{ header }">
    <div class="pointer border-right pa-2">
        <span class="title" @click.prevent="sortBy('name')">
            Nom du ticket
            <v-icon class="ml-2">{{icon.name}}</v-icon>
        </span>
        <v-text-field v-model="searcher.ticket_name.value" type="text"
                label="Rechercher..."></v-text-field>
    </div>
</template>
```

Become (not functional) :

```
<template v-for="(item, i) in headers" v-slot:item.text="{ header }">
    <div class="pointer border-right pa-2">
        <span class="title" @click.prevent="sortBy(item.name)">
            {{item.name}}
            <v-icon class="ml-2">{{icon[item.name]}}</v-icon>
        </span>
        <v-text-field v-model="item.searcher" type="text"
                label="Rechercher..."></v-text-field>
    </div>
</template>
```

If i add the `key` , i have `'<template>' cannot be keyed. Place the key on real elements instead`

and if i remove this i have `Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives`

However I came across several sources that demonstrate the opposite

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt

[Fix: require-v-for-key shouldn't be raised on slots](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/commit/73a9dd46a91016504f33e5877544ebf71392841a)

[vue-language-server : Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608379/vue-language-server-elements-in-iteration-expect-to-have-v-bindkey-directiv)

Thank you

**Edit 20/12 :**

https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1006

How can I make the v-slot attribute dynamically with the vuetify data table ?

Here is my code :

```
<template v-for="(head, i) in headers" v-slot:header[header.value]="{header}">
    <div :key="i" class="pointer border-right pa-2">
        <span class="title" @click.prevent="sortBy('id')">
            {{head}} <br> {{header}}
            <v-icon class="ml-2">{{icon.id}}</v-icon>
        </span>
        <v-text-field v-model="searcher.ticket_id.value" type="text"
                label="Rechercher..."></v-text-field>
    </div>
</template>
```

It cannot be mounted on the table column

I need to use `v-slot:header.id="{header}"` for the mounted on the id column but I have to make `id` dynamic according to my loop

how to do ?

Thank you

**I find it**

I added `head: 'header.id'` in my list so i can use `<template v-for="(head, i) in headers" v-slot:[headers[i].head]="{header}">`

Answer (score 7):

I had to do

```
<template v-for="(col, i) in filters" v-slot:[`header.${i}`]="{ header }">
```

in my case

```
filters: { 'name': [], 'calories': [] },
```