# eslint - disable error notification

Tags: javascript, html, eslint

I'm coding with brackets and I have eslint installed. Eslint keeps telling me that some functions and var's are defined but never used. I think it is because I'm using an external js file which I linked to my html document. My question is how can I disable this error, or tell eslint to not inform me of this error?

Comment: Is there "an .eslintrc.* file or an eslintConfig field in a package.json file"? [configuring](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/user-guide/configuring)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line
@Moritz you can check this question, you can understand how to disable eslint for line, for some part.

Comment: @AndyG Whenever I create a package.json file, eslint doesn't work anymore with the error: "[object Object]"

Comment: I would have thought there would be an existing file with the plugin to modify, rather than creating a new one. But this is the extent of my own knowledge, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this. You can disable it inline, by pasting this line in your source:

```
/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/
```

or if you're using .eslintrc file, you can add this to your rules block:

```
"no-unused-vars": ["off", { "vars": "all", "args": "after-used", "ignoreRestSiblings": false }]
```

Comment: Thanks, the first method works perfectly, but when I create a .bablrc file eslint is still showing me the error. Is there a way to specify globally (for all .js files in my project) the rule?

Comment: Hey @Moritz, try to just switch it off with
"no-unused-vars": 0

And make sure your .eslintrc file is recognized by the editor.