# Ignore the indentation in a template literal, with the ESLint `indent` rule

Tags: javascript, eslint, ternary-operator, lint, template-literals

The ESLint rule for [indent](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent) allows for you to specify which nodes are ignored, when determining whether the rule should apply to that node, using the `ignoredNodes` option.

I've got the following code that I want to ignore with this rule:

```
const a = b
  ? `c${
      d
    }`
  : e
```

Specifically, the line with `d` and the subsequent line are reported as having two more spaces than they should. I want to ignore those lines from the rule, but I can't figure out the node that should apply.

Node types are specified [in this repo](https://github.com/estree/estree). I know that ternary expressions, like used in this code, is a `ConditionalExpression` node, and it seems like a [template literal node](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/master/es2018.md#template-literals) exists, but I can't get it to work.

I know I can use `eslint-disable-next-line`, `eslint-disable`, etc., but I don't want to use those, because then I'd have to use them every time this comes up.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line

Comment: @JaeWooWoo I don't want to use `eslint-disable` etc.

Comment: `"indent": ["warn", 4, { "ignoredNodes": ["ConditionalExpression *"]]` works for me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From looking at an [ast tree](https://astexplorer.net/) with simply `${foo}`, I confirmed that it is truly the `TemplateLiteral` node. However I happened to also know the solution from there: you need to select its children as well ([see the ESLint docs on selectors here](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/selectors)). This can be done with `TemplateLiteral > *`. The reason why your solution wasn't working is because `ESLint` *will* exempt the `TemplateLiteral` from the indent rules, but only the little `${` and `}` parts, not the contents.

This can go into your ESLintrc file as such:

```
"indent": ["error", "tab", { "ignoredNodes": ["TemplateLiteral > *"] }]
```

I'm sorry no one else was able to answer your question sooner.

Comment: I got a warning from eslint using this config, specifically since it expects `ignoredNodes` to be an array. The following fixed it for me:
```js
"indent": [{ "ignoredNodes": ["TemplateLiteral > *"] }]
```

Comment: I didn't get that warning. I've fixed that now.

Comment: It overwrites extended rules for `ignoredNodes`. Can we just extend this array, without overwriting?

Comment: The rule had the wrong syntax, it needed the first 2 parameters (`"error", "tab"`). Now it works without errors

Comment: @B.Bohdan Did you found an solution to extend `ignoreNodes` array without overwriting?

Answer (score 16):

To ignore all indentation and newline errors in ESLint inside a template literal, including function calls or deeply nested JS syntax, you can use `"ignoredNodes": ["TemplateLiteral *"]` (without the `>` child selector, to target all descendants.)

```
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 2, { "ignoredNodes": ["TemplateLiteral *"] }],
    "function-paren-newline": "off"
  }
```

You also have to specify your normal indentation rule, e.g. `"error", 2` for enforcing 2 spaces or `"error", "tab"` for tabs.

`"function-paren-newline"` was also giving errors inside my template literals, I also wanted to disable that (because I'm extending an existing ESLint config that displayed an error for that).