# ESLint - Help identifying indent sub-rule

Tags: javascript, eslint, static-analysis

How can I get ESLint `indent` to like this code:

```
const a = `
  <li
    style=${styleMap({
      color: '#F00',      // bad line
      background: '#0F0'  // bad line
    })}                   // bad line
  >Something</li>
`;
```

It doesn't like the indenting on the lines I marked `bad line`. This is what it wants me to do:

```
const a = `
  <li
    style=${styleMap({
  color: '#F00',
  background: '#0F0'
})}
  >
    <span>Something</span>
  </li>
`;
```

which looks ridiculous.

Here is my current rule regarding 'indent':

```
indent: ['error', 2, { SwitchCase: 1 }],
```

I looked through the [indent](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent) documentation but didn't see anything that seemed to match this scenario.

---

Edit: I went through all of the options for the `indent` rule, set them all to `0` then went through one-by-one setting them to `10` to see which one affects my expression. Looks like `ObjectExpression` is the culprit, but that value is normally good.

It seems like there are some issue dealing with template literal multiple line placeholder object declarations. I think my only recourse is going to be to add it to `ignoreNodes`.

Comment: How about adding line-breaks after `${` and before the corresponding closing brace?

Comment: @AndreNuechter Even doing that, it complains about everything between the `${` and closing `}` line as being too far. Wants me to shove those back so `styleMap(` lines up with the `const`.

Comment: I just tried that snippet in my IDE and I don't get any wild formatting-suggestions (I use almost the same eslint-rule). Is there maybe prettier or beautify in the mix?

Comment: Nope. I'm running `eslint` from the command line directly on the raw JS. The only other thing is I am inheriting from the `google` config set, but I don't think ESLint does partial inheritance for a single rule, so I don't think that should come into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note*: See the bottom of this answer for the final version. Tweaked it further as I continued through linting everything.

Once I narrowed it down a little further, I was able to find some better Google results and found this answer which seemed very similar to my problem, but not quite: [Ignore the indentation in a template literal, with the ESLint `indent` rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178093/ignore-the-indentation-in-a-template-literal-with-the-eslint-indent-rule)

The AST pattern didn't work for my specific case (at least the first one). After poking it with an AST explorer, I ended up going with these patterns:

```
indent: ['error', 2, { 
  ignoredNodes: [
    'TemplateLiteral > CallExpression > ObjectExpression',
    'TemplateLiteral *'
  ]
]
```

The first covers the exact scenario in my question. The second covers a similar scenario:

```
const a = `
  <li
    style=${someFunc(
      'arg1',
      'arg2'
    })}      
  >Something</li>
`;
```

Seems this is ultimately an issue that ESLint is going to have to fix somehow, because the `ObjectExpression` check alone gets really confused inside of a template literal placeholder.

---

EDIT:

I changed the second expression from `TemplateLiteral > CallExpression` to `TemplateLiteral > *` because I found two more slightly different scenarios that weren't caught already. I'd prefer to be more specific, but I don't want to have to identify 80 different scenarios.

---

EDIT 2:

Changed `TemplateLiteral > *` to `TemplateLiteral *` instead because found even more that were nested and not caught by `> *`.

Now, the patterns are just one:

```
indent: ['error', 2, { 
  ignoredNodes: [
    'TemplateLiteral *'
  ]
]
```

Comment: it's also missing an extra ```}``` :)