# Ignore the indent in lit-html html function, with typescript-eslint lint rule

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, lit-html

Don't want to use eslint-disable-next-line, I'd like to ignore all the `html` result

```
import { html } from 'lit-html';
render() {
    // This part will have ugly indent
    return html`<div
      class=${classMap({
        'row-height': true,
      })}
    ></div>`;
}
```

Similar question: [Ignore the indentation in a template literal, with the ESLint `indent` rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178093/ignore-the-indentation-in-a-template-literal-with-the-eslint-indent-rule)

I have tried

`"@typescript-eslint/indent": ["error", "2", { "ignoredNodes": ["TemplateLiteral > *"] }]`

But not working, because `html()` returns `TemplateResult` Object which is defined in `lit-html`, not a AST node type, right?

So is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Related Info:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent#ignorednodes

Comment: Use prettier to format it as a workaround: https://dev.to/s2engineers/how-to-make-eslint-work-with-prettier-avoiding-conflicts-and-problems-57pi

Comment: `"TemplateLiteral ObjectExpression"` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `"TemplateLiteral > *"` by `"TemplateLiteral *"` (i.e. remove the `>` character).

The `>` character indicates to only ignore the direct children. By removing it, you ignore all children, no matter how deep they are nested.