# Modify an ESLint rule for a single line

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm aware of the [single-line syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29592334/35305) to disable an ESLint rule for the current or next line.

What I would like to know is if there is something similar to *modify* a rule for a specific line.

E.g.:

```
// eslint-modify-next-line yoda: ["error", "never", {"exceptRange": true}]
if (0 < count && count <= max) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware you can't modify the rules for a single line but you could modify the rules for that whole file using [ESLint Configuration Comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-configuration-comments)

Comment: Right. I guess I should have mentioned that in my question, too. : )