# Setting up Vue.js with Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, router

I am trying to combine vue with vuex. However there is an error, I am unable to link my `main.js` to and my `app const` to my index.html.

My set up is:

**main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from 'routes.js'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

new Vue({ // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
})
```

**routes.js:**

```
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: HelloWorld,
    name: 'Hello'
  }
]
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>vue-example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but vue-example doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app">
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'Hello' }">Home</router-link>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script src="./src/main.js"></script>
```

My new error:
[image]

Comment: it's a eslint error, to fix it add this `window.vue_app=app;`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim into what file? main.js?

Comment: yes , at the end

Answer (score 3):

### For the original question

As said in a comment, that is an `eslint` error. You much likely setup your project with the vue-cli, which by default ships your project with an eslint configuration. [Eslint is a tool](https://eslint.org/) that checks your code to prevent some kind of errors.

In your case, in `main.js`, you're doing:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
})
```

When you assing to an `app` variable, but you don't do anything with that variable. Eslint complains about that -since, well, having unused vars usually is due to an human error and is a mistake-.

You can just skip the variable assignation, and just:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
})
```

Without the app variable.

or you can add a comment in the line before, like:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
})
```

Your issue, as far as I know, has nothing to do with vuex.

Also, if you really want to use `app` in any other part of your application, just add:

`export default app` at the end of the `main.js` file. This will fix this error too, since now you're actually doing something with the `app` variable.

Some tips:

- You can setup any editor to work with eslint. So the editor itself (like vscode) will give you visual feedback when you violate some eslint rules. Also will setup the comments to ignore eslint rules in specific lines if you want to.
- You can configure eslint behavior [by adding an .eslintrc configuration file to your project](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started). In your particular case, I think is a good thing that eslint forbid you to compile that code (unused vars are misleading at best), but sometimes you may not want to follow some eslint rules, depending upon your code style and many considerations.

### For the question edition

Now that you fixed the previous `eslint` error, you're getting a new one:
`do not use new for side effects`

This eslint rule, again, usually makes some sense: `new` calls are intended to return an object, so you technically should not use `new` without assigning the result to a variable.

However, the `Vue` api actually do that, so you need to ignore eslint this time:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-new
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
})
```

This should do the trick. To understand how you can use comments to disable specific `eslint` rules, [this answer helps a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line).

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented your explanation, but I am getting a new error, please check the code above!

Comment: Thanks! Now the error is gone, however somehow my index.html is not updating with the vue component.. The routerview doesnt seem to be picking up anything..

Comment: Well, what errors do you see in the browser console? Are you using the vue devtools? https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

Comment: @Sergeon I am using the chrome addon, so I can see it, however it is saying that Vue isnt even enabled for the index.html page.

Comment: And how are you launching the page? With `npm run dev` or something? I believe you simply messed something up when configuring the project for the first time, maybe trying to solve the `eslint` issue, and now it does not even compile. If you try the 'npm run lint' or 'npm run build` commands on the terminal, what is the output?

Comment: I am building with `npm run serve`, the `npm run lint` has no errors. `npm run build` has no errors.

Comment: I'm really surprised about that. Usually, when creating a project with vue-cli, you have this comment: '    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->'. You, however, are adding a `script` tag **outside** the html. Maybe you should place your script within the `body` tag, right at the end. But I'm not really sure if this is related with your issue or not.

Comment: @Sergeon Yeah i tried moving into the body tag, nothing interesting happened. I am fairly confused too.

Comment: If you didn't added much code of your own yet, I think the easiest thing maybe is to generate a new vue-cli project and start from scratch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183582/discussion-between-otto-and-sergeon).

Answer (score 1):

This is an [eslint rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) . It prevents you from creating variables that you never use. To disable this rule for this specific line just write:

```
const app = new Vue({ // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
})
```

To disable this rule for your whole project just create a file (if it does not already exist) in your main project directory called `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  rules: {
  'no-unused-vars': 0 //or false,
  }
}
```

Or you just do not assign your vue instance to a variable:

```
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      components: {
        HelloWorld
     }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does my index.html know I want to use the `const app`. Because the link between `div id="app"` and vue is missing..? My helloworld.vue is never displayed on index.html

Comment: The link isn't missing. In your main.js file you have your vue instance defined - the `el: #app` links your vue to the html

Comment: Then how come it isnt working? is the `<script` tag not linking the `main.js` file correctly?