# $ is not defined in ejs file when trying to add and remove class

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am trying to create an active class for my navbar so the people can see what page they are on. I created the JQuery logic in the file but when I try to run my program it brings up an error: "Reference Error, $ is not defined". I tried installing a jquery package but that did not help. Below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
<title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/stylesheets/main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
 <body class="main">

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="/">Cody Blackwood</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/projects">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/info">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/resume">Resume</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-item").on("click", function(event){
    $("li.nav-item").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
   });
 });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
   color: white;
 }

.navbar-nav .nav-item:active .nav-link{
  background-color: white;
  color: #5900b3;
}
```

Comment: I don't see JQuery loaded in your sample code, check the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Bootstrap getting started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/) says:

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery,

So you miss this line from the header:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ejs is a template and it will generate a valid html.
It seems like your code run at server side.

1. Make sure the jQuery has been loaded properly
2. Your js code should be run in client side, warp by `<script></script>`, not `<% %>`
3. Run your code while DOM is ready `window.onload = () => { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Can you explain the third step more to me?

Comment: `<script>
  window.onload = function () {
   $(".nav-item").on("click", function(event){
      $("li.nav-item").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });
  }
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

ejs functions defined between the <% %> are loaded **before** the contents of the page are rendered, so when you try to `$('#id1').doSomething();` jquery won't be able to find the element with `id="id1"` because that element doesn't exist yet.

If you want to modify the nav bar in the way you are describing, you will have to create a

`<script src="jquery.js"></script>`

**underneath** the elements(s) you want to modify.

jquery.js would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav-item").on("click", function(event){
             $("li.nav-item").removeClass("active");
             $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

If you are still having issues after trying this, then you probably don't have jquery setup correctly.
Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js) to learn about setting up jquery on node.js.

If you want to learn how to mute the linter warnings, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line).

### Edit

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-item").on("click", function(event){

    $(this).closest("li").css('background-color', 'red').siblings().css('background-color', 'white');

   });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: I see part of my original error as to why this didn't work. When I use the link to set up jquery correct though, it keeps telling me that the $ is never used but is assigned (var $ = require('jquery')(window);). Is there a common cause of why this happens?

Comment: Does your app crash?  or is it a linter warning?

Comment: It is just a linter warning. I can still run the program fine but the active class still won't work.

Comment: Yeah it does that for me too.  I think linter expects you to use jquery on your server.  I added a link in my answer to learn how to mute these warnings.

Comment: I just updated the code from the original question to what the code looks like now

Comment: what is the "active" class?  and what exactly do you want to happen when you click on a link?

Comment: your problem isn't with the jquery not loading btw.  You would get a 404 (or another error) in the network tab of your inspector.

Comment: When any of the navbar links are clicked I want it to change colors so the user can see which page they are on

Comment: Added updated code in my answer.  That should work for you.

Comment: With the code I currently have posted, I have the active class be added to one of the li's when I click on it but it won't stay active. It will show for a second and then when the page is loaded it will not stay active. Other than that it works now

Comment: I also added the CSS under as well Jane