# How to fix 'eslint(no-unused-vars)' error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

As I have already installed `babel-eslint`,`eslint-plugin-react` and `eslint-plugin-es` in my project and config them in `.eslintrc`, it seems like most of the strange problems eslint output before has been gone.But here is still one problem which makes me very confused.  Here is a function in one of my React component:

```
mouseMove = (e) => {
    window.onmousemove = (e) => {
        // ...
    };
}
```

'e' is declared but never used(no-unuesd-vars)

Comment: If you don't use the variable `e`, just don't declare it and replace `(e)` with `()`

Comment: You could also add an eslint ignore statement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line

Answer (score 2):

If you dont use `e` variable, you should remove it:

```
mouseMove = () => {
   window.onmousemove = () => {
    // ...
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above `e` has been [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) by declaring a function in `mouseMove` scope using an argument named `e` again. There's no way to access the outer `e` inside `onmouseover` so eslint will complain.

You can fix this by removing the argument `e` of `mouseMove` or rename it.

Hope this can help.