# How to disable es-lint error in angular 7 typecript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, eslint, lint

I am working in angular 7 with VS code.I have es-lint rules.I want to disable es-lint error at some case .Is there any plugins for this problem.

```
[tslint] object access via string literals is disallowed [no-string-literal]

      this.validate(res['results']);
```

Comment: That's `ts-lint`. Just do `// tslint:disable-next-line` or `// tslint:disable-line`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off eslint rule for a specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to disable an ESLint rule in a file or on a specific line, you can add a comment.

On a single line:

```
const message = 'foo';
console.log(message); // eslint-disable-line no-console

// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log(message);
```

On the whole (rest of the) file:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
const message = 'foo';
console.log(message);
```