# Flow no-weak-types warning: optional argument of weak type with default value

Tags: javascript, eslint, flowtype

Having this Flow'ed code

```
export default (resource: string, init?: Object = {}) =>
```

I'm getting following warning

> warning  Unexpected use of weak type "Object"  flowtype/no-weak-types

The thing is the `init` argument is exactly native' fetch second argument (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)) which is optional and which is an object that might have more than 10 complicated properties, so I don't want to specify its type rather than generic "Object" or "any".

What is the right way to avoid this warning in my situation?

Comment: The second argument of fetch can also specifically accept a `Headers` object which is much easier to type. That would force you to always use an instance of `Headers` and never a pojo. But I don't see that as a bad thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning you are seeing is from ESLint, specifically the [eslint-plugin-flowtype](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype/blob/master/.README/rules/no-weak-types.md) plugin, and not from Flow itself.

However, it's warning you about something valid. `Object` is an unsafe type in Flow. It is equivalent to `any` (it used to have some subtle differences, but no longer does). In general it is probably worthwhile to spell out the properties explicitly, even if they are complicated, with something like this:

```
type Init = {
  someProp: string,
  someOtherProp: number;
}

export default (resource: string, init?: Init = {}) => {}
```

([try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAkgdgS2FAvFA3gKClAzgewFsIAFAJ3zAC49gyE4BzAGmzyIgHlgALCM8pRpwAroQBG-ANyYAvpkwQAHmHxlkAEwgAzAIYiANsgAUZCARFkAxhBq46DFlAZIA-DXhJUGWQEpUAHw+QA))

You may also want to consider the [`mixed` type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/mixed/), which is safe but inconvenient to use.

If you are sure that you want to accept the unsafe behavior of `Object` or `any`, you can [turn off the ESLint rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line) for that line.

Comment: Thanks! I chose `// eslint-disable-line flowtype/no-weak-types` and it did the trick