# Initializing Google Maps in Util file in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I use `Google Maps` in my `React` app and handle all `Maps API` stuff in a `util` file.

In my `index.html` page, I link to `Google Maps` library -- see below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=my_api_key"></script>
```

The problem I'm having is that in my `util` file, I'm getting **"google is not defined"** error -- see below.
[image]

How do I handle this? I'm linking to `Google Maps` library so I don't think I can import anything because it's not an `npm` package.

Comment: It's just a linting error, not an application error. You can add a lint comment to the top of the file to ignore this lint rule (recommended) or you can update your lint rules to allow `no-undef` (not recommended). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding window as a prefix:

```
const map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.createElement('div'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you including google maps with `<script>` you will get this warning in components too because Google Maps API is added to the global object (window). You can use `window.google` instead, or move to npm package created for Google Maps for example `google-maps-react`, `@react-google-maps/api`, `react-google-maps`.