# Prefer destructuring warning in conditional assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am running this code:

```
const list = [1, 2, 3];
const flag1 = false;
const flag2 = true;

let selection = list[0]; // optimistic

if (flag1) {
  selection = list[1];
} else if (flag2) {
  selection = list[2];
}
```

and my ESLint is throwing this warning:

> Use array destructuring. eslint(prefer-destructuring)

How can I solve this warning in a conditional assignment?

Comment: The message says how: "use array destructuring". There are examples on the rule page, too: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring.

Comment: This isn't a great place to use destructuring though, it seems better to override the rule.

Comment: @pilchard this is why I am asking. I would never use destructuring in a similar scenario (conditional assignation)

Comment: Just disable the rule for the line `// eslint-disable-next-line prefer-destructuring`. see: [Turning off eslint rule for a specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line)