# How to tell ESLint that a certain function or variable is used?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a few functions and variables in one script, that're not used in the script itself, but used elsewhere (in other scripts, or embedded in `on*` event attributes).

How do I tell ESLint not to report those as "defined but never used"? Preferably with all declarations in one place.

Personally, I consider disabling warning for a problem different from solving the problem that caused the warning. Therefore, I rejected the linked post as duplicate (it just demonstrated how to disable 1 specific warning for 1 specific line)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27732209) answer your question?

Comment: @InSync Partially. I'd prefer declaring all those in a single place, but I suppose this solution will do. I'd request this question not be closed in case better solution comes up in the future.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
```