# continue in for await loop NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await

I have the following code:

```
for await (const ele of offCycles) {
      if ((await MlQueueModel.find({ uuid: ele.uuid })).length !== 0) {
        continue;
      }
     <do something>
}
```

Is it possible to use a continue inside a for await loop ?
I received the following error:
Unexpected use of continue statement.eslintno-continue

I would like to continue the loop when the condition is true

Comment: I found that continue is just disallowed as a correct code since it is unreadable.
Sorry for the inconvient

Comment: It's nothing about `async`/`await`, it's just that [that ESLint rule disallows using `continue`, at all](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-continue#rule-details). If you want to use `continue`, you need to turn off the rule (or at least disable it for that line).

Comment: *"*I found that continue is just disallowed as a correct code since it is unreadable.*" FWIW, that's a matter of opinion. Another opinion is that there's a good reason this rule isn't in the default set. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

That's [an eslint error](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-continue), not a JavaScript error.

You can:

- Turn it off in your [ESLint configuration](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules#using-configuration-files)
- Turn it off [on a case-by-case basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line) with a comment
- Follow ESLint's advice and avoid it:

```js
for await (const ele of offCycles) {
      if ((await MlQueueModel.find({ uuid: ele.uuid })).length === 0) {
            <do something>
      }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is just a coding style issue instead of an actual error in JavaScript. Some argues that using `continue` statement is a bad practise but generally it is quite opinionated.

You can disable the rule by adding `"no-continue": "off"` in your eslint config so that you can use it. Read more about the use of this rule here: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-continue

I have found this interesting question here that will explain to you about the use of `continue` / `break`: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/434124/are-there-any-problems-with-using-continue-or-break

Basically, if you know what you are doing, then it is not an issue.